# Django PlanetScale CA Cert Path

Tags: python, django, ssl, environment-variables, planetscale

I have deployed a Django webapp on Vercel which uses a PlanetScale database. I have stored the PlanetScale connection strings as environment variables in Vercel. Django seems to be able to see the env variables; however, I am getting a `FileNotFoundError` for the CA cert path which was provided by PlanetScale. This is causing a server error that takes the app completely offline. This CA path was working previously when stored in a .env file. I have since attempted to replace the .env file and that no longer works either. Nothing else has changed in the project so I am at a loss as how to get this connection established again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I will provide the error stack and settings below:

Error:

```
[ERROR] 2023-06-20T20:00:18.077Z    06fecc12-d46a-4f4f-9cf7-c00e50c42fb4    Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/task/main/views.py", line 21, in home
    currUser = AuthUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 646, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 323, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 299, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 247, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 284, in __init__
    self.ctx = self._create_ssl_ctx(ssl)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 367, in _create_ssl_ctx
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=ca, capath=capath)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 746, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_NAME'),
    'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_PORT'),
    'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'),
    'OPTIONS': {'ssl': {'ca': os.environ.get('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA')}},
  }
}
```

Vercel Environment Variables

```
MYSQL_DB_NAME=<DBNAME>
MYSQL_DB_USER=<PS_USER>
MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=<PS_PASSWORD>
MYSQL_DB_HOST=<PS_HOST>
MYSQL_DB_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I have a feeling because I transferred the environment variables into Vercel, it is appending something unintended to the beginning of the CA path, but since my app can't build and debug is off, I cant see what is being passed.